# Writing in the same column (csv file) C

Tags: c, csv

I have a problem, to write data in a csv file.

The data is saved in the file but all are in the same column.

```
FILE *fichier = NULL;
fichier = fopen("ville_secu_informatique_centroide.csv", "a");
fwrite((pVille + iVille)->Commune, sizeof(char) * 100, 1, fichier);
fwrite((pVille + iVille)->CodeInsee, sizeof(char) * 100, 1, fichier);
fwrite((pVille + iVille)->url, sizeof(char) * 100, 1, fichier);
fwrite((pVille + iVille)->Population, sizeof(char) * 100, 1, fichier);
fwrite((pVille + iVille)->https, sizeof(char) * 100, 1, fichier);
fwrite((pVille + iVille)->Serveur, sizeof(char) * 100, 1, fichier);
fwrite((pVille + iVille)->Versionduserveur, sizeof(char) * 100, 1, fichier);
fwrite((pVille + iVille)->Application, sizeof(char) * 100, 1, fichier);
fwrite((pVille + iVille)->VersionApp, sizeof(char) * 100, 1, fichier);
fwrite((pVille + iVille)->Langage, sizeof(char) * 100, 1, fichier);
fwrite((pVille + iVille)->VersionLang, sizeof(char) * 100, 1, fichier);
fwrite((pVille + iVille)->Latitude, sizeof(char) * 100, 1, fichier);
fwrite((pVille + iVille)->Longitude, sizeof(char) * 100, 1, fichier);
fclose(fichier);
```

I would like to write in different columns in my csv file

Thank for your Help

Comment: output commas...

Comment: "The data registers well," - o'really?

Comment: The data is saved in the file but all are in the same colone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to write a comma between every two columns to get comma separated values.
In addition, no need to use "sizeof(char)", it is always 1.
Also, When you write to the file use the actual length of the string.

for example:

```
fwrite((pVille + iVille)->Commune, strlen((pVille + iVille)->Commune), 1, fichier);
fwrite(",", 1, 1, fichier);
fwrite((pVille + iVille)->CodeInsee, strlen((pVille + iVille)->CodeInsee), 1, fichier);
```